# Why I can't login wordpress admin dashboard regularly?

Tags: wordpress, admin

I had built wordpress site on Sakura server.
But I can't login admin page regularly.
At that time, I have to backup all the source code via FTP, but I want to know why error occur.
When I visit wp-admin, there is 404 error and 'jQuery is not defined' error.
If you have any solutions, please teach me.

Comment: Wordpress uses dynamic data so a database is required. You said you backed up the code but did you back up the database? Wordpress has plugins to migrate websites if that was your plan. What are you trying to do with the WordPress website?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already check database, but there is no errors.
I just found that wp-login.php file was hidden, so I replace that with original one, but I can't edit theme and plugin, though I can login admin page.
Do you know the reason why wordpress site was blocked regularly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its a server problem or please find out theme or plugins folder for any useless code.